# How to Fire Keypress event in IE for a button event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dom-events

I have develop  asp.net application in that I have search option for the clients. When I enter the client name in textbox then I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key from keyboard it is working fine in Firefox and Chrome but didn't fire in IE8 here I have post my code what I did for KeyEvent fire:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function KeyPress() {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) { //if they pressed enter key then..
            document.formname.LoginButton.focus();
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I resolve this to fire the Keypress event in IE? Please help me...

Comment: How do you add this code to the button?

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response just i call the function like .  "<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearchbox" runat="server" onkeypress="KeyPress()"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtNombre" onkeypress="manejadorEnter(this, event)" />
```

Javascript (include it in the code-behind or in HTML):

```
function manejadorEnter(inField, e) {
    var charCode;

    if(e && e.which){
        charCode = e.which;
    }else if(window.event){
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if(charCode == 13) {
        alert("La tecla enter ha sido pulsada en " + inField.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i have try above code what you are giving tome but this one also not fire means when i Press Enter key then it will take action for searching but in above code not perform action .

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried my code shown above and it works fine for all browsers. Just try the following HTML file (obviously enable JavaScript in your browser):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test enter button keypress</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function handlerEnter(inField, e) {
    var charCode;

    if(e && e.which){
        charCode = e.which;
    }else if(window.event){
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if(charCode == 13) {
        alert("You pressed Enter button at " + inField.id);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="txtNombre" onkeypress="handlerEnter(this, event)" />
</body>
</html>
```

For more complicated JavaScript scripts, I strongly suggest to take a look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Good luck!

Comment: Can you give any JQuery link  for keypress event please